# Typescript, Union types, Element implicitly has an 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, typescript-typings

I have next situation, here are several interfaces and types:

```
interface Book {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  author: string;
}

interface Magazine {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  pageCount: string;
}

type Publication = Book | Magazine;

type BookFields = keyof Book;
type MagazineFields = keyof Magazine;

type PublicationFields  = BookFields | MagazineFields;

interface Filter {
  field: PublicationFields;
}
```

I use different react components per each entity, and want to have common sort function, for example:

```
function publicationSort (publications: Array<Publication>, filter: Filter){
  return publications.sort((x, y) => {
    const firstVal = x[filter.field];
    const secondVal = y[filter.field]; 

    //Some lexical or number sort
})
}
```

The problem is: I expect that when calls x[filter.field] then gets a value of given publication, for example I pass a book in the sort function and expect it would work like `const firstVal = book[author]`, instead of it I get the Error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'PublicationFields' can't be used to index type 'Publication'.  Property 'author' does not exist on type 'Publication'`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `author` field doesn't exist on the `Magazine` interface, so `x[filter.field]` could be an invalid field if `x` is a `Magazine` and `field` is `"author"`. One solution is to ensure both interfaces include the same fields:

```
interface Book {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  author: string;
  pageCount?: undefined;
}

interface Magazine {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  pageCount: string;
  author?: undefined;
}
```